How to extract and copy all search results across multiple sheets in LibreOffice Calc?
In an ODS file with multiple sheets, we successfully use the 'Find All' feature to locate cells containing the word 'Steve'.
However, we are unable to copy all these results at once.
Is there a way to extract and copy all occurrences across different sheets?




As you state, selecting an item in the Find summary dialog causes the corresponding sheet to be brought to front, with items selected... and there's no way to select items from the dialog itself. If all you want is the Content, then take a screenshot of that dialog, and use OCR to get the contents as text, though.
